# Removing all items from an array of arrays which are empty of blank

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays and I would like to remove all the items that have elements which are nil or empty after stripping spaces. Look at this snippet:

```
x = Array.new
x << ["A","B", " ", "D"]
x << ["","  ", nil, ""]
x << ["E","Q", "F", "M"]
```

I would like to remove the second record because, it contains no real data.

What would be the best way to do this? Should I simply iterate over the array and and write if-else conditions to test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If using plain Ruby, you can do

```
x.reject{ |arr| arr.all? {|elem| elem.nil? || elem.strip.empty? }}
```

If using rails, thanks to the helper methods you can do

```
x.reject{ |arr| arr.all?(&:blank?) }
```

The key methods are [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000258) and [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank%3F)

Comment: just note that you can use reject! (with !) if you prefer to edit your array instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 4):

```
x.reject { |a| a.join.strip.length == 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If first array will contain nil, when Chubas variant don't work.
Lets slightly modify it:

(using rails)

```
x.compact.reject{ |arr| arr.all?(&:blank?) }
```