# How to compact empty elements in an array

Tags: ruby

Ruby [compacts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) the sequence only if it has nil value, how do I compact "" empty value

Comment: Dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918441/removing-all-items-from-an-array-of-arrays-which-are-empty-of-blank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
a = [1, nil, 2, '', 3]
a.reject{|x| x == '' || x.nil?} # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: -0.5, in the question the OP makes a reference to `compact`, so `select/reject` is the way to go, not a destructive `delete_if`.

Comment: Oops, it really is destructive. Of course, it should be `reject` then!

Comment: +0.5 ;-) yeah, listen to the word, "delete", you can feel its destructive nature on how bad it sounds.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: Agreed. However, `x.empty?` will fail for integers. Originally this was what I wrote :)

Comment: Fair enough, I naively assumed an array of strings that may have `nil`s and empty strings in between.

Answer (score 3):

A similar way of doing it to Sergio's:

```
irb(main):006:0> a = [1,nil,2,'']                   => [1, nil, 2, ""]
irb(main):007:0> a.reject!{|x| x.nil? || x == ''}   => [1, 2]
```

Comment: why `reject!` if the OP referenced `compact`, not `compact!`

Answer (score 3):

I know this has no Ruby on Rails tag, but should you be using the framework, the best solution IMHO is:

```
a = [1, nil, 2, '', 3]
a.select(&:present?)
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

In plain Ruby I'd go with [Sergio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11100930/220147) or `a.select { |x| x.empty? || x.nil? }` if the array can only contain `String`s and `nil`s.